# Symfony - how to generate url with parameters in controller

Tags: php, symfony

I want to generate a url like ../profile/firstname.lastname

But i don't understand how i can do this because i want in my php also the id from the user.

this is my controller:

```
       $controllers
            ->match('profile/{firstname.lastname}/', array($this, 'profile'))
            ->assert('userId', '\d+')
            ->method('GET|POST')
            ->before(array($this, 'checkLogin'))
            ->bind('home.profile');
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more code to help explain the problem you're trying to solve? Where is this code being called?

Comment: I don't have more code because i don't know how to do. Now i can pass the id through the url like profile/1 but i want to pass the names.

Comment: Where did you put that code and what exactly do you want to achieve. Please describe the problem more detailed. You want to generate a URL in a controller-action to ... ? What is that `$controllers` variable in your code example - the `@router` service ... or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build your `Route` like this

```
<route id="profile" path="/profile/{first_name}.{last_name}">
        <default key="_controller">...</default>
    </route>
```

And in controller create like this

> $this->generateUrl('profile', [
>               'first_name' => 'skowron',
>               'last_name'  => 'line'
>           ]);

but if you have 2 profiles with this same data it will give you bad results. Then you can create slug or add `id` parameter to your route

Answer (score 0):

Symfony uses [Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator::generate()](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerator.html) to generate paths. But probably the path is not defined in your routing system. So you must create an instance of it and pass a `RouteCollection` which only contains tha path you want and it does not seem to be a good method.

It's better to use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).